# Стеганография WAV файла

Tags: c#, стеганография

Реализую стеганографический метод LSB для WAV файла. Как доработать мой класс, чтобы вставка происходила согласно данному методу (замена битов файла битами сообщения)? У меня же происходит замена значений аудио файла на байты сообщения, что является некорректным:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using Steganography.Media;


namespace Steganography
{
[Serializable]

//в этом классе скрываем и извлекаем шифруемое сообщение
class HideAndExtract
{
    private WavAudio _file;
    private List<byte> _bits;

    //инициализируем объект класса с помощью класса WavAudio
    public HideAndExtract(WavAudio file)
    {
        _file = file;
    }        

    скрываем сообщение в левом и правом потоках аудиофайла
    public void HideMessage(string message)
    {
        //получаем каналы из файла WaveAudio
        List<short> leftStream = _file.GetLeftStream();
        List<short> rightStream = _file.GetRightStream();

        //скрываем сообщения в потоках

        //преобразовываем сообщение в массив байт
        byte[] bufferMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        short tempBit;
        //место - индекс, который будет идти по сообщению
        int bufferIndex = 0;
        //длина сообщения
        int bufferLength = bufferMessage.Length;
        //длина аудио (длина левого канала равна длине правого канала)
        int channelLength = leftStream.Count;
        //блок хранения сообщения. Это значение равно 1. Если оно не равно 1, то длина шифруемого сообщения больше, чем длина исходного аудиофайла
        int storageBlock = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)bufferLength / (channelLength * 2));

        //если длина сообщения больше, чем длина аудиоканала
        if (bufferLength > channelLength)
            throw new Exception();           

        //сохраняем информацию о длине шифруемого сообщения в первых элементах левого и правого потоков аудиофайла

        //берем целую часть размера сообщения и записываем первым элементом в левом канале
        leftStream[0] = (short)(bufferLength / 32767);
        //берем остаток размера сообщения и записываем первым элементом в правом канале
        rightStream[0] = (short)(bufferLength % 32767);
        var countBufferMessage = 0;
        //идем по длине потока, начиная с 1, так как в [0] хранится длина сообщения; сохраняем бит сообщения в левый и правый потоки 
        for (int i = 1; i < leftStream.Count && countBufferMessage < bufferMessage.Length; i++)
        {
            //берем остаток от деления на 8, так как работаем с битами; также работаем с цифрой 7, так как диапазон [0..7]
            if (bufferIndex < bufferLength && i % 8 > 7 - storageBlock && i % 8 <= 7)
            {
                //получаем бит сообщения
                tempBit = bufferMessage[bufferIndex++];
                //заменяем бит аудиоданных битом сообщения
                //leftStream.Insert(i, tempBit);
                leftStream[i] = tempBit;
                countBufferMessage++;
            }

            if (bufferIndex < bufferLength && i % 8 > 7 - storageBlock && i % 8 <= 7)
            {
                tempBit = bufferMessage[bufferIndex++];
                //rightStream.Insert(i, tempBit);
                rightStream[i] = tempBit;
                countBufferMessage++;
            }
        }
        //в потоках теперь есть введенное сообщение. Обновляем потоки исходного WAV - файла
        _file.UpdateStreams(leftStream, rightStream);
    }

    public string ExtractMessage()
    {
        if (bufferLength > channelLength)
            throw new Exception();

        //получаем каналы из файла WaveAudio
        List<short> leftStream = _file.GetLeftStream();
        List<short> rightStream = _file.GetRightStream();

        //извлекаем сообщение из потоков и отображаем в соответствующем поле

        //индекс в шифруемом сообщении
        int bufferIndex = 0;
        //целая часть длины шифруемого сообщения
        int messageLengthQuotient = leftStream[0];
        //дробная часть длины шифруемого сообщения
        int messageLengthRemainder = rightStream[0];
        //длина аудиоканалов
        int channelLength = leftStream.Count;

        //вычисляем исходную длину шифруемого сообщения
        int bufferLength = 32767 * messageLengthQuotient + messageLengthRemainder;
        //блок хранения сообщения. Это значение равно 1. Если оно не равно 1, то длина шифруемого сообщения больше, чем длина исходного аудиофайла
        int storageBlock = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)bufferLength / (channelLength * 2));

        //создаем сообщение - массив байт
        byte[] bufferMessage = new byte[bufferLength];
        //идем по длине потока, начиная с 1, так как в [0] хранится длина сообщения; сохраняем бит сообщения в левый и правый потоки 
        for (int i = 1; i < leftStream.Count; i++)
        {
            //берем остаток от делания на 8, так как работаем с битами; также работаем с цифрой 7, так как диапазон [0..7]
            if (bufferIndex < bufferLength && i % 8 > 7 - storageBlock && i % 8 <= 7)
            {
                //получаем биты сообщения из левого и правого каналов
                bufferMessage[bufferIndex++] = (byte)leftStream[i];
                if (bufferIndex < bufferLength)
                    bufferMessage[bufferIndex++] = (byte)rightStream[i];
            }
        }
        //преобразовываем массив байт в строковое сообщение и возвращаем его
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufferMessage);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем примере отсутствуют поразрядные операции. Набросал небольшой пример в консоле. Каждые два бита исходного сообщения добавляются в младшие разряды бинарного потока.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace lsb
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] source;
            using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("source.bin", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                int length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
                source = b.ReadBytes(length);
            }
            string sourceMessage = "HELLO WORLD!";
            byte[] bufferMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceMessage);
            source[0] = Convert.ToByte(bufferMessage.Length * 4);
            int offset = 1;
            //шифруем сообщение в бинарный поток
            foreach(byte x in bufferMessage)
            {
                int multiply = 192;
                for (int i = 6; i >= 0; i = i - 2)
                {
                    int output = (x & multiply) >> i;
                    multiply = multiply / 4;
                    int temp = source[offset] & 252;
                    source[offset] = Convert.ToByte(temp | output);
                    offset++;
                }
            }
            using (BinaryWriter b = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("output.bin", FileMode.Create)))
            {
                foreach (byte i in source)
                {
                    b.Write(i);
                }
            }
            int bufferLength = source[0] / 4;
            byte[] bufferOutput = new byte[bufferLength];
            //извлекаем сообщение из бинарного потока
            int step = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < source[0]; i = i + 4)
            {
                offset = 6;
                int multiply = 192;
                int output = 0;
                for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                {
                    int temp = source[i + k];
                    temp = (temp << offset) & multiply;
                    output = output | temp;
                    multiply = multiply / 4;
                    offset = offset - 2;
                }
                bufferOutput[step] = Convert.ToByte(output);
                step++;
            }
            string decodeMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufferOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: да, я понял о чем вы говорите. Не могли бы вы помочь переложить мне то, что вы написали на мой код?